# C# Generics for Comparable Types

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have a function like this, this one is right out of the ITU for H264 video decoding:

```
Clip3(x, y, z)
{
   if (z < x) return x;
   else if (z > y) return y;
   else return z;
}
```

In the ITU documentation, the pseudo-code is listed as sans-data type, implying any numerical data type essentially. Could be a byte, an int, a uint, a double, a float, and so on.

This compiles, but is it the best solution in 2020?

```
dynamic Clip3(dynamic x, dynamic y, dynamic z)
{
   if (z < x) return x;
   else if (z > y) return y;
   else return z;
}
```

Look what happens in the Immediate Window in VS2019 Community though on the first run:

```
(uint)AVC.AVCChunk.Clip3((uint)1, (uint)2, (uint)3)
error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert'
Convert.ToUInt32(AVC.AVCChunk.Clip3((uint)1, (uint)2, (uint)3))
error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'
Convert.ToUInt32(AVC.AVCChunk.Clip3(1, 2, 3))
error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'
AVC.AVCChunk.Clip3(1, 2, 3)
2
(uint)AVC.AVCChunk.Clip3(1, 2, 3)
2
```

Suffice it to say, I'm a little wary of using this method in production. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: I guess a safer approach is to use `IComparable` as most things will be comparable. And the fastest performance wise would be to just create an overload for each type you need.

Comment: Do you mean you can mix types, or all 3 would be the same for any particular call? If the latter is true, you would be better off using generics, limiting the possible choices to value types.

Comment: I'm ok with x, y, z, and the return type being constrained to all being the same type. Writing an overload for byte, char, ushort, short, uint, int, etc etc would be messy and doesn't follow DRY principle. The following does not compile: T Clip3<T>(T x, T y, T z) where T : IComparable. It will still give "Operator '<' cannot be applied to types T and T."

Comment: Same with T Clip3<T>(T x, T y, T z) where T: struct, IComparable, does not compile with same "Operator '<' cannot be applied to types T and T."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can constrain the generic parameter `T` to `IComparable<T>`, and use [`CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netcore-3.1), rather than the `<` and `>` operators:

```
T Clip3<T>(T x, T y, T z) where T: IComparable<T>
{
   if (z.CompareTo(x) < 0) return x;
   else if (z.CompareTo(y) > 0) return y;
   else return z;
}
```

Comment: That's got it, the CompareTo was the kicker. Reflects to the type I expect. So suffice it to say, if implementing generics with IComparable, you can say goodbye to <, >, >=, and <= shorthand and must replace with CompareTo?

Comment: *Reflects to the type I expect*  No, no reflection is involved; all numeric types have a specific implemention of ICompable<T>.

Comment: I meant after I ran .GetType() on the result it gave me the expected result so that’s fine, just asking about the CompareTo necessity.

Comment: @JohnErnest "you can say goodbye to <, >, >=, and <= shorthand and must replace with CompareTo?" Correct. The operators are only defined for the numeric types, not `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: @Sweeper I figured as much, thanks though this gets me where I need to be.